# function call ambiguity with pointer, reference and constant reference parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, overload-resolution, const-reference

What I am trying to do is, allow a pointer, reference or constant reference to be passed with the setter function:

```
class A{
    std::string * p;
    std::string st;

    public:
    A():p(0)
    {}
    A& setS(const std::string& s){
        std::cout<<"called with const std::string&\n";
        st = s;
        p = &st;
        return *this;
    }
    A& setS(std::string& s) {
        std::cout<<"called with std::string&\n";
        p = &s;
        return *this; 
    }
    A& setS(std::string* s) {
        std::cout<<"called with std::string*\n";
        p = s;
        return *this; 
    }
};

int main(){
   std::string s;
   A a;
   a.setS(std::move(s)) //const std::string&
    .setS("")           //const std::string&
    .setS(s)            //std::string&
    .setS(0);           //std::string*
    //if std::string* version is not defined,
    //setS(0) calls the const std::string& version and throws exception 
    return 0;
}
```

But I have seen that, if the pointer version is not there, the `setS(0)` calls the `const std::string&` version of the `setS()` function.

Is there any ambiguity between the pointer and the reference versions or among any others that matter?  Is it well defined and expected to work the same way in all compilers?

Comment: im assuming whats happening is you can create a string from a (null) pointer, and that temporary would bind to a const reference. While undesirable in this case, this seems to be "normal behavior" to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no ambiguity.  When you have `A& setS(std::string* s)` in the overload set then `setS(0)` calls the pointer version and `0` is a null pointer.  It would be the equivelent of `setS(nullptr)`.

When `A& setS(std::string* s)` is not in the overload set then the compiler looks to see if there is a way it can construct a temporary string from `0` and then pass that to `A& setS(const std::string& s)` since a `const&` can bind to  a temporary.  `std::string` can be constructed from a single pointer and again `0` it tread as a null pointer.  So you get a temporary null pointer constructed `std::string` passed to the `const&` function.

This is undefined behavior though.  The constructor for `std::string` requires that the pointer passed to it be a null terminated c string.  If it is not then the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the pointer overload of your `setS` function, the reason you are calling the `const std::string&` version is because of [one of the `std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So `0` is being treated as `NULL`, and interpreted as a `const char*`, from which a `std::string` can be constructed. The `const&` is able to extend the lifetime of the lvalue so it may be passed into that overload of `setS`.

Comment: `0` is not really "being treated as `NULL`", since `NULL` usually just expands to `0`. It is being treated as a null pointer, though.