# Ambiguous function call when Reference and Value overload exist

Tags: c++, oop, overloading

I have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class List {

    void Add(T& item) {//GOOD STUFF}
    void Add(T item) {//More STUFF}
    void Remove(T item) {//STUFF}
};
```

I am trying to use it like the following

```
List<MyClass> list;
MyClass obj;
list.Add(obj); //Here the compiler gets angry :((
```

Regarding the question I have already found the following three SO questions, but I am still not able to call either of the methods.
[Ambiguous call with overloaded r-value reference function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701039/ambiguous-call-with-overloaded-r-value-reference-function)
[function call ambiguity with pointer, reference and constant reference parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649142/function-call-ambiguity-with-pointer-reference-and-constant-reference-parameter)
[Ambiguous Reference/Value Versions of Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857310/ambiguous-reference-value-versions-of-functions)

Comment: I am sorry I will fix now!!

Comment: Considering the names of the function `Add(T& item)` is certainly a mistake! Viewing the signature I suppose the intent is to connect the item to the chain of elements without ownership. So maybe `bind` or `connect` would be a less surprising name. That will avoid you surprising heterogeneous overload behavior. That is bad design.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that `item` being added to `List` will not be owned by the `List` itself. Then I found myself fiddling with function signatures, overloads, references etc

Comment: So I would definitively use a special name, and explicitly disable r-value reference binding: `void bind(T& item){/*...*/} void bind(T&& item) =delete;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ambiguous which function you intend to call, because any l-value being passed as argument to a function can be implicitly converted to a reference, so the ambiguity is unavoidable, as said in [Function Overloading Based on Value vs. Const Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465293/function-overloading-based-on-value-vs-const-reference).

You could change this:

```
void Add(T item) {}
```

to this:

```
void Add(T&& item) {}
```

<kbd>[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/01T6ox71d9648JIm)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me the difference between the two? If i am not mistaken T&& is move semantics

Comment: You are welcome @EmrahSüngü, I updated my answer with a somewhat related link to your question. I know it's not an exact duplicate, but it should explain it to you. Hope that helps.

Comment: I see I seee `any l-value being passed as argument to a function can be implicitly converted to a reference, so the ambiguity is unavoidable.`

Comment: could you please tell me that after I change the signature to T&& how can I call either of the methods?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü updated my answer again, now the Live demo should answer your question. ;)